# Free controls for showing OLAP cubes

Tags: asp.net, olap, cubes

is there a free set of controls to be used for representing the OLAP cubes in aspx pages? something like the ones from Dundas, but free and (if possible) cross-browser.

Thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 1):

We coded a web OLAP viewer in-house (ASP/HTML/JavaScript) and it was incredibly complex, and took a long time. The users simply demanded more features.

There is a MS Office v10 plug-in or ActiveX control you can slap on a web page to view a cube....I think it will work over HTTP, but you're going to get grief somewhere along the way, sorry.

Comment: You're talking about Office Web Components which requires a valid Office license to use and only works in IE since it's an ActiveX component.  More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Components

Answer (score 1):

Currently we use JPivot which is actually Java and should be hosted inside an appserver, I'd suggest you search google a bit as there is bound to be an open source solution for what you want to do out there somewhere.

http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/olap_viewer_software/ might help (first hit for google "OLAP Viewers ASP")

Answer (score 1):

The open source [Ranet library](http://code.google.com/p/ranet-uilibrary-olap/) might meet your needs.  It uses Silverlight and is fully programmable.  There are commercial licenses availalbe too if required.